# React input masks to use with material ui

Tags: material-ui, react-tsx

so I am currently in a predicament, I need a way to mask my MUI OutlinedInput fields but every single library I come across has a specified number of characters that need to be specified, for example if I want a phone number, but I don't have a set number of characters I expect the user to type out then react-input-mask doesn't work for me since I have to specify the length in the mask. I used react imask, but since it doesn't work well when a default value is specified I kind of have to replace that library.

I'm kind of really desperate here, if someone could help me with this It would be very appreciated